# ELF program segments offset in file

Tags: elf

I have a question,about elf program segments offsize in file. For example , a program `readelf -f xx -W` like this:

```
Program Headers:

  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040 0x0001f8 0x0001f8 R E 0x8
  INTERP         0x000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x4ca8e6 0x4ca8e6 R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x4cb000 0x0000000000acb000 0x0000000000acb000 0x035db8 0x04ed80 RW  0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x4ed4c8 0x0000000000aed4c8 0x0000000000aed4c8 0x000230 0x000230 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254 0x000044 0x000044 R   0x4
  TLS            0x4cb000 0x0000000000acb000 0x0000000000acb000 0x000010 0x000018 R   0x10
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x3dcf04 0x00000000007dcf04 0x00000000007dcf04 0x024c64 0x024c64 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...

   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame .gcc_except_table 
   03     .tdata .init_array .fini_array .jcr .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .tdata .tbss 
   07     .eh_frame_hdr 
   08
```

The first load begin at offset `0x000000` and the size is `0x4ca8e6`. why the second offset not (`0x000000  +  0x4ca8e6`), I see the (`0x4cb000 - 0x4ca8e6`) content, all 0. I can't get it. What the rule about the offset in file?

Answer (score 1):

> The first load begin at offset 0x000000 and the size is 0x4ca8e6. why the second offset not (0x000000  +  0x4ca8e6)

Because the loader `mmap`s `LOAD` segments directly into memory, for each `LOAD` segment the following *must* be true:  `(p_vaddr - p_offset) % page_size == 0`.

On `x86_64` the maximum page size is 2MiB (`0x200000`). This places severe restriction on the second (and subsequent) `LOAD` segment location.

Comment: The first load p_vaddr is 0x0000000000400000, memsize is 0x4ca8e6,align is 0x200000.so, align size is 0xa00000. The offsize   0x000000  + 0x4ca8e6 = 0x4ca8e6.Last, ( 0xa00000 -  0x4ca8e6 ) % 0x200000 need 0. Now need append zero bytes to it. But why the last p_vaddr is   0x0000000000acb000  and the last offset is   0x4cb000 .